# JS DOM and Bootstrap: trouble setting visibility with JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

It's the strangest thing...

You can see the full code in action at [keypad.io](http://keypad.io)

When you hit the "sign in" button, the password feild blinks instead of being hidden like it should.  Snippit:

```
function doSignIn(){
  document.getElementById("pass").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

I am able to get it to work properly with a test html doc not using bootstrap, but the full site just blinks and reverts.   I've been pouring over google and stack overflow for a solid hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are causing a page reload throught the submit event!!

Deny the submit with using the preventDefault() function as long there is no needed value typed!

Comment: Of course!  Thanks, I totally forgot that was there.